# learn python and find the libraries

Tags: python, python3

I have learnt that python has a vast repository of libraries and functions that can be used to straightaway implement some really cool projects.

Where can I find these libraries and the corresponding documentation so that everything that I learn is in a systematic way rather than hopping from one website to another. Specifically, I have to implement machine learning algorithms/models and image processing modules/tasks to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answer is too obvious, but have you tried

https://docs.python.org/3/library/

Answer (score 0):

sklearn and matplotlib are useful for machine learning. Knowledge of numpy and scipy can come in handy. One advice: don't just pic up the documentation and start learning about different functions and classes unless you are comfortable with the theory of that particular topic. The modules are quite big. Otherwise, look up the tools in these modules on the go as you learn about them in the class.